# How to Change the Apache document root To /

Tags: apache2

This is a dumb idea but is there a way to set the document root to /, after I tried ddoing this I got a 403 forbidden error

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on your aim why you would want to do that? Maybe a simple `Alias` would suffice if you want to break out of your standard document root?

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason to use / as documentroot, nor is there a reason to use user root as apache user, nor to use root for a group, nor to use any permissions higher than 755 (preferring 750) for dirs and 644 (preferring 640) for files.

Linux users need to take security serious (and the maintainers of apache put up a roadblock for us to be able to use / and a user root).

The basic setup of apache from Ubuntu is perfect as it is and does not require changing the user and group apache is setup with.

With that perfectly clear and since we are here to answer questions ...

Answer to the title. Use the directive:

```
DocumentRoot "/"
```

Do understand that part of the documentation for documentroot states:

> The DocumentRoot should be specified without a trailing slash.

so you are violating basic security with this. Not sure if it is enforced though.

Regarding ...

> 403 forbidden error

This shows up because your website user does not match the owner, and group, of /. You can circumvent the error by running apache with a user root but you will run into a snag: it is not possible by just changing settings.

The file `/etc/apache2/envvars` can be used to change the user and setting it to root would be ...

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=root
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=root
```

But it is not possible to use this without recompiling apache as "root" is hard coded as "not allowed as a user". If you decide to go that route you are on your own.

The directive and a recompiled apache would allow you to use / as documentroot.

Comment: Since we are already talking bad ideas: Do you happen to know if the "don't use root" is linked to `UID=0` or to the name `root`? In the latter case one could do the madness and add another `UID=0` user `www-root` in `passwd` and use it ....

Comment: No idea but it would really be insane if it was not UID=0 :D

Answer (score 0):

You must edit `/etc/apache2/envars` and change:

```
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP
```

... like this:

```
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=yourusername
```

Comment: How would this help?